# Vaadin: Component isn't centered

Tags: java, vaadin

I want the registration form to be in the center of the page and tried to use the same code from this [tutorial](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/modern-web-apps-with-spring-boot-and-vaadin/adding-a-login-screen-to-a-vaadin-app-with-spring-security), but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import com.example.tvseriestrackingwebapp.backend.service.UserService;
import com.example.tvseriestrackingwebapp.ui.components.SignUpForm;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H1;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.HighlightConditions;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.RouterLink;

@Route(value = "registration")
public class SignUpView extends VerticalLayout {


    private UserService userService;

    private final SignUpForm signUpForm = new SignUpForm();

    public SignUpView(UserService userService) {
        //signUpForm.addListener(SignUpForm.SignUpEvent.class, this::saveUser);
        setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
        setSizeFull();
        setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        add(new H1("TV Series Tracking Web App"), signUpForm);
    }

    private void saveUser(SignUpForm.SignUpEvent event) {
        userService.save(event.getUser());
        System.out.println("Saved user");
    }


}
```

**EDIT**
My view currently looks like this 
[image]

And I would like it to look like this.

[image]

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to work.` - *what* doesn't work? what does it look like? How do you expect it to look like?

Comment: @kscherrer I edited the post

Comment: Are you still looking for the answer?

Comment: Please share SignUpForm constructor it is possible it has width set to 100%

Comment: Voting to close as this Question lacks important debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the width of your `signUpForm` is 100%.

Set the width of your form to the desired value, lets say 500px to start with. As long as the element has a width of 100%, any justify-content will not be applied because there is no extra space.

```
signUpForm.setWidth("500px");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the width of the child component (signUpForm) shouldn't be set to 100%.